# Split a string on multiple characters in python

Tags: python, regex, string, split

I am trying to split a string on multiple characters in python just like I am doing in Java like this:

```
private static final String SPECIAL_CHARACTERS_REGEX = "[ :;'?=()!\\[\\]-]+|(?<=\\d)(?=\\D)";
String rawMessage = "let's meet tomorrow at 9:30p? 7-8pm? i=you go (no Go!) [to do !]";
String[] tokens = rawMessage.split(SPECIAL_CHARACTERS_REGEX);
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(tokens));
```

Here is the working demo with the correct output: [Working Demo](http://ideone.com/BuiNRM)

I am trying to do exactly the same in python, but when I am doing that it would not tokenize at all if I just add the 'single quotes' character in the regex. How do I create the same resultant parse results from python as from Java program above?

This:

```
import re
tokens = re.split(' \.', line);
print tokens
```

For line:

```
"let's meet tomorrow at 9:30p? 7-8pm? i=you go (no Go!) [to do !]"
```

Gives:

```
["let's meet tomorrow at 9:30p? 7-8pm? i=you go (no Go!) [to do !]";]
```

When I was it to do this:

```
[let, s, meet, tomorrow, at, 9, 30, p, 7, 8, pm, i, you, go, no, Go, to, do]
```

Comment: why would it remove the `'p'` and the `'pm'`?

Answer (score 2):

Use the same regular expression you used in Java:

```
line = "let's meet tomorrow at 9:30p? 7-8pm? i=you go (no Go!) [to do !]"
tokens = re.split("[ :;'?=()!\\[\\]-]+|(?<=\\d)(?=\\D)", line)
tokens = [token for token in tokens if len(token) != 0] # remove empty strings!
print(tokens)
# ['let', 's', 'meet', 'tomorrow', 'at', '9', '30p', '7', '8pm', 'i', 'you', 'go', 'no', 'Go', 'to', 'do']
```

Comment: doesn't work, the 'p' and 'pm' are still attached to something else.

Comment: Yes, the 8 and pm are still attached. Suggestions?

Comment: `tokens = [token for token in tokens if token]` is slightly more idiomatic way of filtering.  (I would probably dispense with the meaningful name as well `tokens = [s for s in tokens if s]`).  Less Pythonic would be `tokens = filter(None, tokens)`.

Answer (score 2):

Here's an alternative that *finds* rather than splits:

```
>>> s = "let's meet tomorrow at 9:30p? 7-8pm? i=you go (no Go!) [to do !]"
>>> re.findall(r'\d+|[A-Za-z]+', s)
['let', 's', 'meet', 'tomorrow', 'at', '9', '30', 'p', '7', '8', 'pm', 'i', 'you', 'go', 'no', 'Go', 'to', 'do']
```

If it is ok to keep letters and numbers together use `'[0-9A-Za-z]+'`.  For letters, numbers, and underscore use `r'\w+'`.

Comment: +1 You might want to quote this from the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.split): "Note that `split` will never split a string on an empty pattern match" (hence why it is not splitting on `(?<=\d)(?=\D)`).

Comment: @Jerry:  Are you sure you meant this comment for my answer?

Comment: Yup. Using `split` is not the ideal solution here and I believe that, with what's given, it's safe to assume that OP's only looking for alphanumeric characters.

Answer (score 0):

Use the following code

```
>>> chars = "[:;'?=()!\-]+<" #Characters to remove
>>> sentence = "let's meet tomorrow at 9:30p? 7-8pm? i=you go (no Go!) [to do !]" #Sentence
>>> for k in sentence: #Loops over everything in the sentence
...     if k in chars: #Checks if the variable is one we want to remove
...             sentence = sentence.replace(k, ' ') #If it is, it replaces it
...
>>> sentence = sentence.replace('p', ' p').replace('pm', ' pm').split() #Adds a space before the 'p' and the 'pm', and then splits it the way we want to
>>> sentence
['let', 's', 'meet', 'tomorrow', 'at', '9', '30', 'p', '7', '8', 'pm', 'i', 'you', 'go', 'no', 'Go', 'to', 'do']
```

If you want to use `regex`:

```
line = "let's meet tomorrow at 9:30p? 7-8pm? i=you go (no Go!) [to do !]"
tokens = re.split("[ :;'?=()!\\[\\]-]+|(?<=\\d)(?=\\D)", line)
tokens = [token for token in tokens if len(token) != 0]
tokens = tokens.replace('p', ' p').replace('pm', ' pm').split()
print(tokens)
#['let', 's', 'meet', 'tomorrow', 'at', '9', '30', 'p', '7', '8', 'pm', 'i', 'you', 'go', 'no', 'Go', 'to', 'do']
```

Comment: sure, but I thought I could use some smart regex to avoid having to iterate over a list. Besides, if "p" or "pm" is part of a word like "apt", it will turn it into "a pt" which is not correct.

Comment: Algorithmic complexity here is quadratic.  This has the potential to be quite inefficient.

Answer (score 0):

That split regex in Java should have worked the same in Python.
Its probably a bug. The confusion would probably be the overlap
between `\D` and `[ :;'?=()!\[\]-]`, and how it handles that (bug~).

You could try to solve it by putting `(?<=\d)(?=\D)` first, but it
has to be coerced to do that.

This regex here forces it to do that. Is this a workaround?
I don't know, don't have python to test with. But, it works in Perl.

Coerced regex -

```
 #  (?<=\d)(?:[ :;'?=()!\[\]-]+|(?=\D))|(?<!\d|[ :;'?=()!\[\]-])[ :;'?=()!\[\]-]+

    (?<= \d )
    (?:
         [ :;'?=()!\[\]-]+ 
      |  (?= \D )
    )
 |  
    (?<! \d | [ :;'?=()!\[\]-] )
    [ :;'?=()!\[\]-]+
```